# Howto reference an Array in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to have a reference to an array for better coding, but I don't know howto do. The following code should illustrate what I mean:

I have a class, with an Array of Array of Objects as follow:

```
class Group: NSObject {
    var alGroup = [[NSObject]]();
}
```

I have the following 2 different codes from which I would like to prefer using the first one.

code 1, which doesn't work with a reference to the inner array. With not working I mean the object is lost (no syntax or runtime error) :

```
func addObjectto_new_Group(o:NSObject, inout group:Group){
    var alGroup = group.alGroup;
    var alNew = [NSObject]();
    alNew.append(o);
    //group.alGroup.append(alNew);   
    alGroup.append(alNew);
}
```

Code 2, which works, but not preferred:

```
func addObjectto_new_Group(o:NSObject, inout group:Group){
    //var alGroup = group.alGroup;
    var alNew = [NSObject]();
    alNew.append(o);
    group.alGroup.append(alNew);   
    //alGroup.append(alNew);
}
```

How can I have a reference to an array like in code 1 ?

Comment: Just do group.alGroup instead of making a new variable of it?

Comment: And you dont need inout if its a class unless you want to make it a new instance.

Comment: But I wrote I do prefer code 1 if possible and you suggest to do code 2. ?

Comment: Code 1 will not work unless you at the end  do group.alGroup = alGroup

Answer (score 0):

When you create your 'alias' variable `var alGroup = group.alGroup` you do not copy by reference, but by value as explained in the comments to your question. So one way to solve this is to use the full name like in `group.alGroup.append(alNew)`.

However there is a another option which might be to your liking:

```
func addObjectToNewAlGroup(o:NSObject, inout alGroup : [[NSObject]])
{
    var alNew = [NSObject]()
    alNew.append(o)
    alGroup.append(alNew)
}

var aGroup = Group()

addObjectto_new_Group("a1", &aGroup)
addObjectto_new_Group("b2", &aGroup)
addObjectToNewAlGroup("c3", &aGroup.alGroup)
```

This uses your 'Code 2' version, and a new function doing the same, but passing the array by reference into the function. This is legal, and does work. It is only references within a function which doesn't work as you want.